# Is there a way to check for file name that is started with digit?

Tags: python, directory

I have written this code:

```
fileName = []

def listdir(k):

    files = os.scandir(k)
    for f in files:
        if f.is_file() and f[0].isdigit():
            print('this is a file')
            print(f)
            fileName.append(f)

        else:
            listdir(f)

listdir(path)
```

but I received an error message for `if f.is_file() and f[0].isdigit()`
Error message: `TypeError: 'posix.DirEntry' object is not subscriptable`
My file name typically looks like this `9867_1_dimensional-set-shifting_results.csv` but there is some files like `.DS_Store` and text file inside the directory. I want to see if there is a way to check for files that are ended with `.csv`.

Comment: `f` is not a string. It's a [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry]). Try looking at `f.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `os.path.splitext(path)` separates the path + file name from the extension name.
then, you can get tuple.

```py
os.path.splitext("C:/User/9867_1_dimensional-set-shifting_results.csv")  

>>>
('C:/User/9867_1_dimensional-set-shifting_results', '.csv')
```

Using `os.walk()` function can get all files in every directory.

```py
def get_filepath(path):
    fileName = []
    for path, folder, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] #extansion
            if ext == '.csv':
                file_path = path + "/" + filename
                print(file_path)
                fileName.append(file_path)
    return fileName

get_filepath("your path")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating through the files, you have to make sure that you are treating f as a string. To do this just simply get the name of the file by doing:
`f.name`

Your code should look something like this in the end:

```
fileName = []

listdir(k):
    files = os.scandir(k)
    for f in files:
        if f.is_file() and f.name[0].isdigit():
            print('this is a file')
            print(f)
            fileName.append(f)
        else:
            listdir(f)

listdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the file name from file pointer:

```
fileName = []


def listdir(k):
    files = os.scandir(k)
    for f in files:
        if f.is_file() and f.name[0].isdigit():
            print('this is a file')
            print(f)
            fileName.append(f)

        else:
            listdir(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would be helpful:

```
import os

fileName = []

def listdir(k):

    files = os.scandir(k)
    for f in files:
        if f.is_file():
            if f.name.split('.')[-1] == 'csv':
                print('this is a file')
                print(f)
                fileName.append(f)
        else:
            listdir(f)

listdir(path)
```